# Next js Slow ChatGpt data streaming once deployed

Tags: reactjs, node.js, stream, openai-api

It works fine locally the streaming is perfect. I have deployed it to the AWS server. It works but the data is too slow. Streaming is not working properly. There is an issue that delays for 1 to 2 sec.  I am also using the Edge function in my code. Please let me know why it is happening like this. Why is it streaming data too slow? I am calling the API directly not using an SDK or NPM module for OpenAi.

Note: Next js version 13.
There are two file.
under /pages/api/streaming.ts
and a component Home.tsx where I have an action function.

I have below code:

```
export const runtime = "edge";
export default async function handler(req: any) {
  const { prompt } = await req.json();

  const res = await fetch("https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions", {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: `Bearer ${key}`,
    },
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify({
      model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
      messages: [{ role: "user", content: prompt }],
      temperature: 0.7,
      top_p: 1,
      frequency_penalty: 0,
      presence_penalty: 0,
      max_tokens: 1000,
      stream: true,
      n: 1,
    }),
  });

  return new Response(res?.body, {
    status: 200,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "text/event-stream",
      "X-Content-Type-Options": "nosniff",
    },
  });
}
 const handleGenerateResponse = async () => {
    setShowResponse(true);
    setResponse("");

    const response = await fetch(`${baseUrl}api/streaming`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        prompt,
      }),
    });
    if (!response.body) {
      throw new Error("Response body is null or undefined from ChatGpt API.");
    }
    const reader = response.body.getReader();
    console.log(reader, "reader");
    const decoder = new TextDecoder();
    function onParse(event: ParsedEvent | ReconnectInterval) {
      console.log(event, "event");
      if (event.type === "event") {
        try {
          if (event.data === "[DONE]") {
            return;
          }
          const data = JSON.parse(event.data);
          data.choices
            .filter(
              ({ delta }: { delta: { content?: string } }) => !!delta?.content
            )
            .forEach(({ delta }: { delta: { content?: string } }) => {
              setResponse((prev: string) => {
                return `${prev}${delta.content}`;
              });
            });
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
      }
    }
```